# Show progress bar until it load the data in UIWebView IOS7

Tags: ios, pdf, uiwebview, progress-bar

Hi in my application i have `UIWebView` which loads the `pdf` file using URL its very large file its taking too much time to load. Now i want show the user that like its **loading progress** until it get load the my pdf once my file loaded its has hide the progress bar, how can I achieve this?

My webview code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];

   NSString *pdf =@"http://jesusredeems.com/mag/pdf/JRE-2014-03.pdf";

   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:pdf];

   NSURLRequest *myRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
   [webview loadRequest:myRequest];

}
```

I'm using the above code to load my `pdf`, how I can use the progress bar for file loading?

Comment: Swift version is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32532405/how-do-i-display-the-loading-progress-for-a-uiwebview-and-the-actual-uiwebview-o

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should start/stop the progressbar in webview delegate methods.

Add following line in your `viewDidLoad`.

```
webview.delegate = self;
```

Add following functions in your controller...

```
-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    //Start the progressbar.. 
    return YES;
}

-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    //Stop or remove progressbar
}

-(void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    //Stop or remove progressbar and show error
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes why not, use `UIWebView` delegate method

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];

   webview.delegate=self; //Assign Delegate

   [webview loadRequest:myRequest];

   [self showProgress];//Show Progress

}
```

Use delegates as below

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{
    if(!webView.isLoading){ //This ensures whether the webview has finished loading..
       [self hideProgress];
    }
}
- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error{
   [self hideProgress];
}
```

Cheers.